# Open source zooming timeline library

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, zooming

I need to draw a zoomable timeline using C# and WinForms. What I want exactly is a line with points of time from which there are edges to vertices with information about what happened in these points of time. The zooming feature is really important. Interactivity (possibility for user to move the vertices with infomation) would also be great.

Can you advise any open-source library for that?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a user control for TimeLineEvent (vertical line with time line event properties and implementations like Data and Time, etc) and a user control for TimeLine that acts as some collection of TimeLineEvents.
For zooming, I would add a property like ZoomBounds and maybe Scale, etc, and override the onPaint event to draw only the zoomBounds (and over the whole timeline bounds).

There's no open source library I've ever heard of to support timelines.
Anyways, because you have a specific need for the timeline, you are most likely not going to find what you need, and better just start from scratch yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Gantt charts are usually zoomable. It might be much easier to implement one from Teleric or Infragistics. Depending on your requirements, those may incorporate 90% of the functionality you need, and they are extendable.